# VSCodeでワークスペースが未設定になってしまった

Tags: macos, vscode

VS Codeを変にいじってしまい、ワークスペースが未設定になってしまい調べたものの設定方法が分かりません！
アドバイスお願い致します！

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

正確には、「未設定」という名前のワークスペースを作成した、という状況だと思います。

このワークスペースの名前を変更したい、ということであれば、次の手順で行なえます。

1. `未設定.code-workspace` というファイルがどこかに作成されていると思うので、これを探す。

   - 場所がわからない場合は、 VSCodeのメニューから **ファイル > 最近使用した項目を開く** を選択してみると、それっぽいパスが表示されると思います。
2. ファイル名を所望のワークスペース名に変更する。
3. VSCodeのメニューで **ファイル > ワークスペースを開く** を選択し、このファイルを選択する。

Comment: ありがとうございます！解決しました！